# Java 8 : How to convert timestamp to long

Tags: java-8, timestamp

I am writing a back-end service and receive timestamp as shown below

```
Instant timestamp = Instant.now().plusMillis(offset);
bodyObject.put("timestamp", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(timestamp));
```

Now at my service end I want to convert this timestamp into `"Long"` data type for my further processing. Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am converting the timestamp format to `Instant` and then using `getEpochSecond()` method to get seconds

```
Instant instant = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(format));
instant.getEpochSecond();
```